# Rails query with inner join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How to write this sql

`select * from interview_questions as iq inner join (select * from interview_answers as iaa where iaa.case_id=6 and iaa.used='t') as ia where iq.id = ia.interview_question_id;`

with Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord? An interview_questions has many interview_answers, is a 1 to N relationship. I want to obtain the list of InterviewQuestion that this sql query would normally return.

Comment: An interview_questions has many interview_answers ? And interview_answers belongs to many interview_questions ? Shortly is it a N for N relationship?

Comment: Yes, an interview_questions has many interview_answers It is an 1 to N relationship.

Comment: One answer cannot belong to many questions?

Comment: In the actual database non. One answer cannot belong to many questions?

Comment: Not the answer the user typed but the option, you see? For example one question can have the answer option 'bla' and another question can have 'bla' as an option too. But since it is the actual answer it makes sense to be a 1 to N association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a 1 to N relationship between your models you need to use The has_many Association like this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Rails guides explains:

> A has_many association indicates a one-to-many connection with another model. You'll often find this association on the "other side" of a belongs_to association. This association indicates that each instance of the model has zero or more instances of another model. For example, in an application containing authors and books, the author model could be declared like this:

You probably gonna need to do this:

```
class interview_questions < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :interview_answers
end

class interview_answers< ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :interview_questions 
end
```

After that you need to create a migration to add foreing key in your interview_answers model.

```
rails generate migration add_interview_questions_to_interview_answers interview_questions:references
```

Finally you can use association helpers like

```
interview_questions.first.interview_answer.where(case_id: 6).where(used: 't')
```

Remember that this is just an example, you will probably need to adapt some minor things. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After the associations were done as suggested by @Gabriel Mesquita I needed this to complete my task.

```
InterviewQuestion.where(id: InterviewAnswer.where(case_id: params[:case_id], used: 't').pluck(:interview_question_id))
```

was the Ruby on Rails code that I looked for. It selects all interviews_questions that have an interview_answer corresponding to the current case_id and with the used set to 't'.